# Root site collection for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

This seems obvious, but why can't I use the Publishing Portal template for my root site collection on SharePoint online?  Is this a Microsoft issue/error, or is it this way for some logical reason?  If it can be done, how is the best way to use this template and if it can't be done what template should be used for your root site collection on SharePoint online?

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: Have you tried enabling publishing features on the root site?

Comment: Want to use the Publishing Portal template so I don't have to enable other features.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The root site collection is provisioned for you automatically, you do not get to specify the template.

If you want to use the publishing aspects of SharePoint, turn on the Publishing Infrastructure site collection feature and the SharePoint Publishing site feature and you'll be in business.

Comment: Any reason Microsoft uses the Team site template?  Seems odd that they chose that template when the Root Site Collection is usually the landing page for SharePoint.

Comment: It is sort of the standard? you can do pretty  much anything on a team site that you can do on a specialized template with the right features enabled. You could try deleting it, purging it from the recycle bin, and recreating it. You might want to do that in a test tenant first as idk the ramifications as such.

Answer (score 0):

Huhm! I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. Coz, I could create a site collection using Publishing template.

[image]

Comment: My question was specific to the Root Site Collection only, but thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The scripting capabilities are turned off by default for Personal Sites, Self-Service cerated sites and Root Site Collection in order to maintain the security and integrity of the sites in your tenancy. 
Refer: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f